# Best way to display flow motion in a SVG?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, inkscape

I want to create a web page that's showing stuff like flowing fluids. For this I want to use SVG graphics where the start and stop of the (repeating) motion is controlled via JavaScript.

This motion can be easily shown by a way like this hand drawn GIF:
[image]

But how can I achive such a look by simple means in a SVG? Especially as this also has to flow around corners, i.e. not only a linear motion is required...

Preferably already (semi-automatically) creatable in Inkscape...

Comment: Not sure about SVG, but http://nerget.com/fluidSim/this fluid dynamics simulation has been implemented in JavaScript using `canvas`. If you have a look at the source code, it's pretty easy to follow. It says that it's based on the Navier Stokes equations. You should look up Lattice Boltzmann method as well. I'm not 100% on this, but I think the Lattice Boltzmann may be a discrete method for approximating the Navier Stokes equation.

Comment: @Joe: the link is wrong: [here](http://nerget.com/fluidSim/) the correction

Comment: @Joe - thanks for the link to this great demo! But I'm sorry that I have to say that this doesn't even closely relate to my question :( I wand to display "fake" motion that could animate the flow in pipes like at http://www.em-ebook-shop.com/lshop,showdetail,24648,d,1339931570-10245,technische_grafiken,050-r-f-profi,3,Tshowrub--technische_grafiken,0.htm

Comment: This page has a [number of demos](http://srufaculty.sru.edu/david.dailey/svg/#JSAnim), one of which is http://srufaculty.sru.edu/david.dailey/svg/curve.svg. I'm sure if you look at it, you can determine how they did it. Going around corners and shapes is a bit more challenging, but there are some other demos on that page that show that too, plus several tutorials are online.

Comment: @Jared Farrish: thanks, I'll start looking there. Inbetween I also found http://owl3d.com/svg/vsw/articles/vsw_article.html which I think is also heading in the right direction...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, now I found the answer to the "first" part of the question, i.e. the **upper "flow"**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   version="1.1"
   width="202"
   height="32"
   id="svg2">
  <g id="layer1">
    <path
       d="m 1,16 200,0"
       id="path1"
       style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:30" />
    <path
       d="m 1,16 200,0"
       id="path2"
       style="stroke:#ff0000;stroke-width:20" />
    <path
       d="m 1,16 200,0"
       id="path3"
       style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:16;stroke-dasharray:48, 48;stroke-dashoffset:10.6" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

That was created in Inkscape (+ simplifications by hand afterwards to post only the relevant stuff) just by duplicating one line with different widths, a very big one (`id=path1`) in black for the surrounding, a big one (`id=path2`) for the red fluid and a small, dashed one (`id=path3`) that'll be used for the animation later on.

All that's now left to do is to change the `stroke-dashoffset` attribute via JavaScript or an CSS animation as that'll move the little bars to indicate flow. E.g.:

```
   <style type="text/css">  
      @keyframes move {  
        from {  stroke-dashoffset: 0;  }  
        to   {  stroke-dashoffset: 96;  }  
      }  
      @-moz-keyframes move {  
        from {  stroke-dashoffset: 0;  }  
        to   {  stroke-dashoffset: 96;  }  
      }  
      @-webkit-keyframes move {  
        from {  stroke-dashoffset: 0;  }  
        to   {  stroke-dashoffset: 96;  }  
      }  
  </style>
```

and then in the `<path id="path3">` element:

```
  animation-duration: 3s;  
  -moz-animation-duration: 3s;  
  -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;  
  animation-name: move; 
  -moz-animation-name: move; 
  -webkit-animation-name: move; 
  animation-timing-function: linear; 
  -moz-animation-timing-function: linear; 
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear; 
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
```

Note: the path can have any shape, it doesn't need to be straight :)

**The lower flow:**
By using the ideas of http://owl3d.com/svg/tubefy/articles/article3.html I also found a solution (better: workaround) for the "lower flow". The idea is just to clone the path multiple times and use differently colored dashes drawn over each other. The animation goes as above. Both together can be seen now at: http://jsfiddle.net/pXkvD/2

Comment: You could add this as a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) - would be interested to take a look!

Comment: Nitpicking: there should be no dash before the unprefixed properties, e.g "-animation-name" should say "animation-name" for example. And because prefixing is so much fun, why not add -o-, and -ms- too, for Opera and IE respectively.

Comment: @ErikDahlström you are absolutely right. I've corrected it above as well as in the fiddle that can be found at http://jsfiddle.net/pXkvD/2/ now.